# vim columns length resetting

Tags: vim, text-editor, word-wrap

I am trying to set the columns variable in vim to be 80. If I set it in .vimrc, there seems to be no change. I'm using gVim 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

In my cpp files, the existing long lines do not change to being wrapped at the 80 column mark. If I start typing a new long line, it will not wrap at 80. If I set columns while the file is open with :set columns=80, the long lines are wrapped at 80 columns, but after a few seconds then wrapping goes away and it's like I never set columns.

The columns variable DOES work when I'm typing git commit messages. It just doesn't work in source files.

Below is my .vimrc file. Is there something in there that is resetting the columns? I have tried to disable my plugins, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
" Allows Vim-related packages in Debian to work
runtime! debian.vim

" **********************************************************
" Everything in this ******* section is *required* for vundle for work properly

" debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'. Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER explicitly setting 'compatible'.
" Set nocompatible for everything to enforce this
set nocompatible
filetype off

" Set runtime path to include vundle
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'

" Install youcompleteme
Plugin 'Valloric/youcompleteme'

" Install NERDTree
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

" Install xmledit
Plugin 'sukima/xmledit'

" Haskell
Plugin 'dag/vim2hs'

" detect file type
filetype plugin indent on

" **********************************************************


" Set highlighting for syntax
syntax on

" Set colorscheme
colorscheme elflord 

" When we split a window, make sure we can write to that file
set noreadonly

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
set background=dark

" Make the finding feature not worry about case until you use capital letter
set ignorecase
set smartcase

" Makes the lines auto indent       
set smartindent

" Makes tab key use spaces instead of literal tabs
set expandtab

" Sets how many columns a tab counts for
set tabstop=2

" Makes all existing tab characters match current settings
retab

"Sets how many characters are used for indentation
set shiftwidth=2

"Makes backspace delete over line-breaks, automatically inserted indents, etc
set backspace=2

" Enables mouse use when you press 'a'
set mouse=a

" Show line numbers
set number

" Sets the number of commands to remember 
set history=50

" Sets the status line to always be present
set laststatus=2

" Enables incremental searching
set incsearch

" Sets the amount of lines to have above or below the cursor at all times
set scrolloff=2

" Set the number of text columns to use before wrapping line
set columns=80



" Options for auto completion
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview


" ================= Configure Taglist ================= "
" Lets the tag list plugin use ctags
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = "/usr/bin/ctags"

" Make Taglist split the window horizontally
let Tlist_Use_Horiz_Window = 1

" Set the Tlist window height to be half of the overall window height
" This lets the NERDTree and Taglist share half of the vsplit window space
" To make the Taglist window be half of the split size, you must also change 
" taglist.vim in if block: "if g:Tlist_Use_Horiz_Window" (~ line 1350), 
"                          change let win_dir = 'botright' to let win_dir = 'rightb'. 
" 'botright' will make it take over the bottom of the entire vim window
let Tlist_WinHeight = winheight(0) / 2
let Tlist_WinWidth = winwidth(0) / 2






" ================= Configure YouCompleteMe =================
let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion = 2
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.ycm_extra_conf.py'

" This represses the confirmation of loading a .ycm_extra_conf file.
" It should probably be left alone, but it is annoying to always confirm when
" working on my own projects everyday.
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0

" This closes the preview window that appears after you have selected a
" completion option
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1




" ================= Key Bindings ================= "

" Build tags for current directory with Ctrl-F12
map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+pl --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>

" Create a command to toggle NERDTree and TlistToggle at the same time
com TT NERDTreeToggle | TlistToggle



" Map a key to the TT command
noremap <F6> :TT<cr>




" ============ Colemak remappings ============ "
function! SetColemakRemaps()
    " Remap the scrolling keys for colemak
    noremap n j|noremap e k|noremap i l
    noremap gn gj|noremap ge gk

    " Remap undo key
    " l to u
    noremap l u|noremap L U

    " Remap yank and paste keys
    " j to y
    noremap j y|noremap J Y 

    " Remap insert keys
    " u to i
    " y to o
    noremap u i|noremap U I
    noremap y o|noremap Y O

    " Remap next key for search
    " k to n
    noremap k n|noremap K N

endfunction
" ========================================= "





" ============ Norman remappings ============ "
function! SetNormanRemaps()
    " Remap the scrolling keys for norman
    noremap n j|noremap i k|noremap o l|noremap y h
    noremap gn gj|noremap gi go

    " Remap insert keys
    " r to i
    " l to o  
    noremap r i|noremap R I
    noremap l o|noremap L O

    " Remap yank and paste keys
    " j to y
    " f to p (this is different from conventional 
    "  paste location because ; is in p's location)
    "  f (r in qwerty) is p in Colemak so I'm used to that mapping
    noremap j y|noremap J Y
    noremap f p|noremap F P

    " Remap next key for search
    " p to n
    noremap p n|noremap P N

endfunction
" ========================================= "




" Set key remaps based on which keyboard layout
" is in use - works only for Colemak and Norman layouts
" Relies on 'check_kb_layout.sh' script
function! SetLayoutRemaps()

  call system('. ~/check_kb_layout.sh')

  if v:shell_error == 1
    call SetNormanRemaps()

  elseif v:shell_error == 2
    call SetColemakRemaps()

  endif

endfunction
" ========================================= "


" Call the remap function
call SetLayoutRemaps()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'columns'` option is the number of columns of the screen (physical size) which is usually set by the terminal. What you want is `'textwidth'` which maximum width of text to be inserted.

A common mistake is setting buffer local options like `'textwidth'` or `'shiftwidth'` in your `~/.vimrc` file. It would be best to set these by filetype and use `setlocal` when setting these options. Get the buffer's filetype via: `:set filetype?`

E.g. Assuming filetype is `javascript` then add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugins/javascript.vim`:

```
setlocal textwidth = 78
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'tw'
:h 'co'
:h :setl
:h options
:h after-directory
```

Comment: I see. Well I tried setting tw, but it didn't change anything. When I set both tw and columns, it did resize my window to the specified amount. However, it didn't wrap with a line break when I got to the end of the line.

Comment: Setting `'textwidth'` will not change things upon change. You will need do some reformatting via `gq` or `gw`. See `:h gq` and `:h gw`. You may also want to look at `:h 'formatoptions'` and `:h fo-table` to change how formatting occurs. A common setting is `:setlocal formatoptions+=a` which will auto-format content is inserted.

Comment: Okay I set formatoptions+=tcaw and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!